# Disable click after x times

Tags: jquery, click, mouse

Let's say the user is able to click a button (div) 7 times. After clicking it 7 times, the button must disappear or become non clickable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This should work although you'll need to flesh out some details yourself. The button:

```
<div class="button">button</div>
```

The JS:

```
<script>
$('div.button').click(function() {
  var tally = ($(this).data('clicks') || 0) + 1;
  if ( tally < 7 ) {
    $(this).data('clicks', tally);
    console.log(tally);
  }
});
</script>
```

I've simply stopped processing the click, but you can hide the button of course without too much effort.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$('button').data('count', 0).on('click', function (e) {
    var $t = $(this),
        count = ++($t.data('count'));

    // kill it with fire
    if (count === 7) {
        $t.remove();
    }

    // increment the count
    $t.data('count',count);

});
```

This way, you avoid global variables and keep your count associated to the particular elements it pertains to. (Just imagine if you have hundreds of these buttons!)

Comment: Make it into a jQuery plugin! I posted a `.nth()` function once, which was like `one()` but for `n` clicks.

Comment: When I try this code I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation on 'count = ++$t.data('count');'.

Comment: Also where is the count incremented? I am missing a line '$t.data('clicks', newCount);' somewhere in the code

Comment: @Olle ~ woops! sorry about that! :D updated the code to increment the count.

Comment: @Blender ~ now **that** is a great idea. :D

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two methods of doing this...

### Using closure

Just define variable outside the event handler and increase it with every click. Then just check what value it has. It could look like this:

```
// method 1 - using closure
(function(){
    var click_counter = 0;
    jQuery('#link1').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = jQuery(this);
        click_counter += 1;
        if (!el.hasClass('inactive')){
            // should be activated
            alert('Clicked the link ' + click_counter + ' time(s)');
        };
        if (click_counter >= 7){
            // deactivate
            el.addClass('inactive');
        };
    });
})();
```

### Associating click counter to the element using `jQuery.data()`

You can also use one of the jQuery's features for attaching data to the elements. It could look like this:

```
// method 2 - using jQuery.data()
jQuery('#link2').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = jQuery(this);
    var click_counter = (el.data('click-counter') || 0) + 1;
    console.log(click_counter);
    el.data('click-counter', click_counter);
    if (!el.hasClass('inactive')){
        // should be activated
        alert('Clicked the link ' + click_counter + ' time(s)');
    };
    if (click_counter >= 7){
        // deactivate
        el.addClass('inactive');
    };
});
```

### Live examples

You can see both codes work correctly - just follow this link to the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3wt8h/

### Disclaimer for jQuery < 1.7

If your version of jQuery is older than 1.7, you will not have `.on()` function available. Just use `.bind()` instead, it should work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a `click` handler to the div
2. each time the user clicks increment a global count.
3. when the count === 7, set the `visible` css class to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to **increment a variable as part of the click action** to keep track of the number of times the button has been clicked.

*You should avoid having this variable be global.* You can do this by declaring the variable within the scope of a function, and have that function set up the click behavior.

With jQuery:

```
function initClick () {

    var clickCounter = 0;

    jQuery('#myLink').click(function (e) {
        if (clickCounter >= 7) {
            return;
        }
        // do stuff
        clickCounter++;
    });

}

initClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#myDiv').data('clickCount',0).click(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var clickCount = Number($this.data('clickCount')) + 1;
        if(clickCount <= 7){
            //Perform click action here
            $this.data('clickCount',clickCount);
        }
        if(clickCount == 7){
            $this.hide();//for example
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.button").click(function(){
   var count = parseInt($(this).data("clicks_count"));
   if(isNaN(count))
      $(this).data("clicks_count","0");
   else if(count>=6)
      $(this).hide();
   else
      $(this).data("clicks_count",count+1);
});
```

and off course in your html add the button with the relevant class, 
i.e.:

```
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do

http://jsfiddle.net/einar/E9Wkr/

```
var countclick = 0;

$(".button").on("click", function() {
    countclick = countclick + 1;
    if (countclick >= 7) {$(".button").off("click"); } 
});
```